# find the difference between two columns in an ssrs matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have the following ssrs matrix that I am building :

```
Month(Column)
Sales(Rows)               SalesData (Data)
```

My data looks something like this :

```
           Jan  Feb March 

  Sales     10    3   9
```

What I would like to do now is to find the difference between each of the rows to show 
  something like :

```
            Jan   Feb  March
Sales        10    3    9
#change           -7    6
```

In an ssrs table its a simple expression .

I do not know how I need to do it in a matrix since the Months Columns are generated dynamically

Please direct me..

Just wanted to add this to clarify :

This is how my matrix looks

```
                          Month(Column)
Sales(Rows)               SalesData (Data)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use SUM function and provide name of you column group as second parameter?

Comment: I am looking to find the difference between two adjacent rows of my column .. Not sure if your solution would work

Comment: What did you end up doing? I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the row group and put 'Add Total' 
[image: Total Group]
**After**

Then click on the area that they up the Total for you.
In the value section add an expression like: `Fields!YourOtherFieldToCalculate.Value - Fields!YourFieldToCalculate.Value`

If you are dealing with the same values you could add this

```
ReportItems!SomeTextBox.Value - ReportItems!SomeOtherTextBox.Value
```

(though I think you would have to add it into the footer)

With your new clarification I would go with Sam's use of Previous: though I would have used but his checks for nulls which is a good thing!

```
=Fields!Column.Value - Previous(Fields!Column.Value)
```

Comment: Fields!YourFieldToCalculate.Value - Fields!YourFieldToCalculate.Value gives me 0 .

Comment: Sorry should be Fields!YourFieldToCalculate.Value - Fields!YourOTHERFieldToCalculate.Value If you are calculating the same values then it will equal 0; 5 - 5 = 0 etc. I will change above to resent it correctly.

Comment: Hey , I understood what you just said.. but I have just one Field that gets grouped by month. I have edited the question to make it more clear. I do not have two fields to subtract. I have only one field that gets grouped by month that I need to subtract. Please let me know .

Comment: did you ever figure this out?