# Adding Difference column on SSRS Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I would like to get some help on adding a difference column (net difference between months) on the matrix shown below. I've tried several solutions provided on different websites but the value doesn't show the correct value.

```
Column: Date
Value: metric
```

[image: http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn21/chirojenic/diskspace_zpsho72jxeg.jpg]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you want your difference column to show? The remaining disk capacity or the net change in disk usage between months?

Comment: the net change in disk usage.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148560/